# Merging SpatialPoints and SpatialPolygons Dataframes in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have downloaded data from the sp package

```
library(rspatial)
California_shp <- sp_data("counties")
Houses <- sp_data("houses1990.csv")
```

`California_shp` is a SpatialPolygon Dataframe and `Houses` is a SpatialPoints Dataframe.

I am trying to merge the `Houses` object to `California_shp`

I have been advised to use the `point-in-polygon` operation and the `mean` function but I am not sure where to start with this.

Comment: If you want to use the `point-in-polygon` function then you'll need the coordinate vectors for both `Houses` and `California_shp`. Do they have that information?

Comment: 'Houses' has latitude and longitude and 'California_shp' is a shapefile so I assume you can get the coordinates from that?